# View linked PDF as popup within Google Sheets

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is probably a wild question but I was curious if there is ANY way with Apps Script to open linked PDF documents in some kind of iFrame-popup within Google Sheets?

I am trying to set up this database tool within Google Sheets for non-profits to manage applications and it would be kinda cool to go through them faster if they could just view them in the same window...

Anyhow, would appreciate any push into the right direction! Have a good day

Comment: function present_pdf() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<p>A change of speed, a change of style...   </p>   <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/fileid/preview" width="480" height="720" ></iframe>')
    .setWidth(960)
    .setHeight(720);
  ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'My add-on');
}

function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('My Menu')
    .addItem('My menu item', 'present_pdf')
    .addToUi();
}
I tried to replace the id or url when mouse click using onSelectionChange trigger.

Comment: But with that trigger, the ui service does not work. So it would be better after each link, you should create a button in which assign the function to get id or url. When each time you click the button you can preview the pdf in the modal dialog popout in the spreadsheet.